# Is it possible to get the "Image Path Name" of csrss.exe which is a SYSTEM process?

Tags: windows-7, elevated-privileges

The windows system process (in Windows 7 for this example) "csrss.exe" runs as a SYSTEM process and when I go to get (programmatically, of course) the process list with pid, command line, and image path name I get no values for command line or image path name because Windows won't let you grab that information for a SYSTEM process (I believe).

Is there a way I can grab image path name from a SYSTEM process? Does Windows actually prevent you from doing this? Is there a workaround?

Update: calling ReadProcessMemory() function

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915312.aspx]

Comment: The link you posted is for Windows Mobile 6.5, are you working in this environment? Or did you mean: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx for Windows API development?  Perhaps tag the question with the domain you are working in to help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way (much easier than ReadProcessMemory, which is also possible if you know where to look) to do this is with [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489%28VS.85%29.aspx), you'll see on that MSDN page further references;

> TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS 0x00000002
>
> Includes all processes in the system
>   in the snapshot. To enumerate the
>   processes, see [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684839%28VS.85%29.aspx).
>
> Note that you can use the
>   [QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to
>   retrieve the full name of an
>   executable image for both 32- and
>   64-bit processes from a 32-bit
>   process.
>
> **szExeFile**  The name of the executable
>   file for the process. To retrieve the
>   full path to the executable file, call
>   the *Module32First* function and check
>   the *szExePath* member of the
>   *MODULEENTRY32* structure that is
>   returned. However, if the calling
>   process is a 32-bit process, you must
>   call the **QueryFullProcessImageName**
>   function to retrieve the full path of
>   the executable file for a 64-bit
>   process.

Pretty straightforward.

Comment: This is not correct at the moment. Microsoft's page on CreateToolhelp32Snapshot explicitly says that it will not work for the Csrss processes(and possibly neither for others like it).

To make this work you need to enable SeDebugPrivilege.
See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610391/get-path-of-csrss-exe