# Get path of Csrss.exe

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi

I want to get the path of a PID pointing to Csrss.exe. I cannot use the OpenProcess function because MSDN specifically states that it will return ACCESS_DENIED on processes such as Csrss.exe and Idle. I have tried using

```
Process32Next
```

to get a

```
PROCESSENTRY32
```

structure, which has an exeName field. However, that's just the name of the executable. You can get the full path by calling

```
QueryFullProcessImageName
```

However, that function takes in a HPROCESS which unfortuanately requires a call to `OpenProcess`.
I need to do this because I'm trying to verify if a process is a Microsoft Signed Process, and so I get the PIDs of the processes and in order to check if it's signed, I have to get the path to the process.

Comment: Try to call OpenProcess when you have [debug privillages](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?251376-getting-the-pid-or-handle-to-csrss-exe&p=761327#post761327).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @Dai I'm basically trying to verify if the processes created in my secure environment are authentic windows applications, because Windows sometimes creates random processes inside of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out there is new function in Vista and above for getting process path and new process access ([`PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights)):

You can get the handle of the process with this permission.Here is the sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,  // token handle 
    LPCTSTR Privilege,  // Privilege to enable/disable 
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege  // TRUE to enable. FALSE to disable 
)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = { 0 };
    // Initialize everything to zero 
    LUID luid;
    DWORD cb = sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES);
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, Privilege, &luid))
        return FALSE;
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege) {
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    }
    else {
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
    }
    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, cb, NULL, NULL);
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
int main()
{
    HANDLE curHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
    OpenProcessToken(curHandle, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &curHandle);
    BOOL b = SetPrivilege(curHandle, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE);
    wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH] = L"";
    int pid = 668;
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    if (handle)
    {
        GetModuleFileNameExW(handle, 0, buf, MAX_PATH);
        std::wcout << buf << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error = " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    char s[MAX_PATH] = "";
    DWORD len = MAX_PATH;
    if (handle)
    {
        QueryFullProcessImageName(handle, 0, s, &len);
        std::cout << s;
    }
    if (handle)
        CloseHandle(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try this when I get the chance.

Comment: Hmm, OpenProcess still returns 0.

Comment: @User12341921 You need to enable [debug privillages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--) and run the program in administrator mode.I have changed my code and you can refer to it.

Comment: Thank you for updating the code! I tried it and it works well. However, the only downside is that I have to run the process as admin. Is it impossible to get csrss.exe path without admin?

Comment: @User12341921 Yes, you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283919/i-found-this-code-to-get-windows-write-privileges-but-it-does-not-working).